# ASIHTTPRequest on iPad: "The request timed out"

Tags: iphone, ios, asihttprequest

My application allows the user to download relatively large files (~120 MB) from my own dedicated server. I'm using the [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) library for downloading.

It may sound weird, but everything worked fine until yesterday. I've tried downloading files countless times both from my app (on an iPad) and a Mac, and while on the Mac the download succeeds, on the iPad it randomly times out. Sometimes it goes until 100%, sometimes it reaches 30%-40% or something and then ASIHTTPRequest's `downloadFailed:` selector gets called. If I print out the error's `localizedDescription`, I get "The request timed out".

What could this mean? Could it be a problem of my app? Or a problem with my server, or my connection? I realize this could depend on several factors, so please ask me any information you need if necessary. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had weird network situations like timeouts on my ipad when using wifi that started after the upgrade to 4.2, but were intermittent.

Going to Settings -> General -> Reset Network settings and then reentering the wifi settings solved it for me.

(Also check that someone hasn't recently setup a new nearby wifi access point on the same channel as your network!)

Answer (score 0):

Does your server have limit about the number of connections ? I encountered a problem because the number of connections are too much, then the server declines those connections. Then, they are time out.

Comment: I don't think this is the case, because I'm the only one using the server at the moment.

Comment: Could you monitor the status of connection between server and app? You can use some software tools to trace the status of connections.

Answer (score -2):

Do you use WiFi or 3G connection? Non-WiFi connection allows to download files with maximum size of 20Mb only.

Comment: I'm using WiFi. The same connection that I used on the Mac.